# How can I set subquery to get single records with latest date and maximum id?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to set a query that gets as result a table with single records for a specific column values from the main table, each record must have the newest date and if the latest date is the same in multiple records, i need only one record with the greatest id.

Up to now I'm using

```
Select id, p_id, max(date), column1, etc
From table
Group by p_id
```

But I need the other part to have single record for p_id each with latest date and greatest id among the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (p_id) t.*
from mytable t
order by p_id, date desc, id desc
```

For each `p_id`, this gives you the row with the greatest `date`. Column `id` is used as a tie-breaker.